# I want to scrape a list of chapters from a manga using Playwright

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, css-selectors, playwright

Currently I'm scraping a manga. The issue I have is that, while I succeeded in getting one chapter, I still can't figure out how to get an array of all the chapters.

The way I got the chapter was by choosing the CSS selectors of each the cosnt chapter and const name. Now I understand this is not practical for an array of chapters so I tried a function that retrieves all the CSS selectors of the elements inside each chapter element and logs them to the console. I can't make it work out yet, so I ask for a helping hand around here.

```
import playwright from "playwright";

(async () => {
  let browser;
  let context;
  try {
    const url = "https://battwo.com/title/75019-blue-lock";
    const yearUrl = "https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/blue-lock"; // Replace with the URL containing the year element
    const userAgent =
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";

    // Start the browser, observe the process.
    browser = await playwright.firefox.launch({ headless: true });

    // Create a new incognito browser context. Set User Agent Method (Avoid block requests).
    context = await browser.newContext({ userAgent });

    // Create a new page in a pristine context. Set ViewportSize.
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.setViewportSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });

    // Set the timeout to 2 minutes
    page.setDefaultTimeout(180000);

    // Page to extract data.
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 60000 });

    // Open a new page to scrape the year element from another URL
    const yearPage = await context.newPage();
    await yearPage.goto(yearUrl, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 60000 });

    // Wait for the selector to appear on the page.
    await yearPage.waitForSelector("div.pure-1.md-1-5 > span.iconYear", { visible: true });

    // Extract the innerText from the year element.
    const year = await yearPage.$eval("div.pure-1.md-1-5 > span.iconYear", 
      (element) => element.innerText.replace(/[-?]/g, "").trim());
    
    // Wait for the chapterElements selector to appear
    await page.waitForSelector("main.px-3 > div:nth-child(3) > astro-island:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)", { visible: true });

    // Scrape the list of chapters and their names
    const listItems = await page.$$("main.px-3 > div:nth-child(3) > astro-island:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
    const chapters = [];
    for (const item of listItems) {
      const chapter = await item.$eval("div.px-2:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)", (element) => element.innerText.trim());
      const name = await item.$eval("div.px-2:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)", (element) => element.innerText.trim());
      chapters.push({ chapter, name });

      // Get all CSS selectors inside the chapter element
      const selectors = await item.$$eval("*", (elements) => {
        return elements.map((element) => element.tagName);
      });
      console.log(selectors);
    }
    
    // Store the scraped data in an object.
    const scrapedData = {
      year,
      chapters
    };
    console.log(scrapedData);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e); // If an error occurs, log it
  } finally {
    console.log("...Scraping");

    // Wait for a random time between 8 to 15 seconds.
    const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15000 - 8000 + 1)) + 8000;
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    if (context) await context.close();
    if (browser) await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The page offers pretty limited CSS selectors to work with, but nonetheless I caution against using `>` and `nth` in selectors--those [long hardcoded selector chains](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors) tend to be unreliable.

Instead, I'd try to hook into ids, classes and attributes that appear distinctive. `[name="chapter-list"] [class="space-x-1"]` was the selector that I ultimately settled on, since `name="chapter-list"` is a distinctive container, and the element with the exact class name `"space-x-1"` is the container for the chapter link and name span.

```js
import playwright from "playwright"; // ^1.38.0

let browser;
let context;
(async () => {
  const url = "<Your URL>";
  const userAgent =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  context = await browser.newContext({
    userAgent,
    javaScriptEnabled: false,
  });
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.route("**/*", route =>
    route.request().url() === url
      ? route.continue()
      : route.abort()
  );
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const sel = '[name="chapter-list"] [class="space-x-1"]';
  const chapters = await page.locator(sel).evaluateAll(els =>
    els.map(e => ({
      chapter: e.querySelector("a").textContent,
      name: e.querySelector("span").childNodes[2].textContent,
    }))
  );
  console.log(chapters);
  console.log(chapters.length); // => 238
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Other notes:

- Since the data you want is baked into the static HTML, you can disable JS and block requests as shown above.
- Avoid element handles. Prefer locators.
- Avoid sleeping (prefer locators and event-driven programming), but if you must, use `import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";` and `await setTimeout(delay)` rather than hand-rolling `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));`.